# android studio: unable to resolve HttpClientBuilder

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I'm facing a strange issue On android studio.
I'm using apache libraries for make some http request, and i need to change

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

that is deprecated with

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

but android studio don't find that package.
How can i do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add to `build.gradle` and sync

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

4.3.5.1 is the latest version :)